# Regular expression: repeating groups only getting last group

Tags: regex

My data:

```
stack: 123 overflow: 456 others: - st: 7 ov: 7 againothers: - m: 11 t: 12 - m: 13 t: 14 - m: 15 t: 16 - st: 8 ov: 8 againothers: - m: 17 t: 18 end: 42
```

My regular expression:

```
^stack: (\d+) overflow: (\d+) others: ?(.+) end: (\d+)$
```

Which matches the groups as:

```
1: 123
2: 456
3: - st: 7 ov: 7 againothers: - m: 11 t: 12 - m: 13 t: 14 - m: 15 t: 16 - st: 8 ov: 8 againothers: - m: 17 t: 18
4: 42
```

Good so far. On group 3 then run the following regular expression:

```
^(?:- st: (\d+) ov: (\d+) againothers: ?(?: - m: (\d+) t: (\d+))+)+$
```

that does not work at all(why?), so I remove the `^` and `$` and it matches. The match then looks like this:

```
1: 7     // <-- Works as expected.
2: 7
3: 15    // <-- Here I'd expected 2 groups matching: (13,14), (15,16)
4: 16    // <-- but I'm only getting the last group.
1: 8     // <-- This works and the remainder is as expected.
2: 8
3: 17
4: 18
```

I seem to be missing "13, 14" my inner group that matches one or more `(?: - m: (\d+) t: (\d+))+` combinations.

Online test: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?33urf, in case that gets butchered, my data there is: `- st: 7 ov: 7 againothers: - m: 11 t: 12 - m: 13 t: 14 - m: 15 t: 16 - st: 8 ov: 8 againothers: - m: 17 t: 18` and the regex is: `(?:- st: (\d+) ov: (\d+) againothers: ?(?: - m: (\d+) t: (\d+))+)+`.

I've read http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html, and I think my problem is related to that? Any tips/pointers/help so I can match one or more m:t: combinations?

Comment: you'll have to go deeper!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most regex engines do not allow multiple captures from the same set of parentheses within a repeating group.  If capturing parentheses match more than once, you get what matched last as the result.

The simplest work-around is to make a regex for only that sub-pattern and then get the results captured from each time it matches.

In other words, first get the relevant portion of the string and then use a regex like this on it:

```
/ - m: (\d+) t: (\d+)/
```

(Using whatever mechanism your language uses to match *all*).

Answer (score 2):

Your groups get following numbers

```
^(?:- st: (\d+) ov: (\d+) againothers: ?(?: - m: (\d+) t: (\d+))+)+$
          1         2                            3        4
```

They are numbered by the opening brackets.

If this expression is now matched a second time, then the content from the capturing groups is overwritten.

You are [repeating a capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

As I know in .net it is possible to access all those matches, but in all other regex implementations the group content is overwritten.