# RegEx repeating subcapture returns only last match

Tags: regex

I have a regexp that tries to find multiple sub captures within matches:

https://regex101.com/r/nk1Q5J/2/

`=\s?.*(?:((?i)Fields\("(\w+)"\)\.Value\)*?))`

I've had simpler versions with equivalent results but this is the last iteration.

the Trick here is that the first group looks for a sequence that begins with '=' (to identify database field reads in VB.Net)

The single sub capture cases work:

Match 1. [comparison + single parameter read call]
`= False And IsNull(Fields("lmpRoundedEndTime").Value)`

=> G2: `lmpRoundedEndTime`

Match 3. [read into string] `oRs.Open "select lmpEmployeeID,lmpShiftID,lmpTimecardDate,lmpProjectID from Timecards where lmpTimecardID = " + App.Convert.NumberToSql(Fields("lmlTimecardID").Value),Connection,adOpenStatic,adLockReadOnly,adCmdText`

=> G2: `lmlTimecardID`

Match 4. [assignment]      `Fields("lmlEmployeeID").Value = oRs.Fields("lmpEmployeeID").Value`

Where I am failing is a match with multiple sub-captures. My regexp returns the last (intended) sub capture :

Match 2. [read multiple input parameters]      `Fields("lmpPayrollHours").Value = App.Ax("TimecardFunctions").CalculateHours(Fields("lmpShiftID").Value,Fields("lmpRoundedStartTime").Value,Fields("lmpRoundedEndTime").Value)`

=> G2: `lmpRoundedEndTime`

'''''''''''' ^ must capture: lmpShiftID , lmpRoundedStartTime , lmpRoundedEndTime

I've read up on lazy quantifiers etc, but can't wrap my head around where this goes wrong.

References:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html

Related:

[Regular expression: repeating groups only getting last group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136998/regular-expression-repeating-groups-only-getting-last-group/15137261#15137261)

[What's the difference between "groups" and "captures" in .NET regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320823/whats-the-difference-between-groups-and-captures-in-net-regular-expression)

BTW, I could quantify the sub capture as {1,5} safely for efficiency, but that's not the focus.

EDIT:

By using negative lookahead to exclude the left side of comparisons,  this got me much closer (match 2 above now works):

`(?:Fields\("(\w+)"\)\.Value)(?!\)?\s{0,2}[=|<])`

but in the following block of code, only the first two are captured:

```
        If oRs.EOF = False Then
            If CInt(Fields("lmlTimecardType").Value) = 1 Then
                If Trim(oRs.Fields("lmeDirectExpenseID").Value) <> "" Then
                    Fields("lmlExpenseID").Value = oRs.Fields("lmeDirectExpenseID").Value
                End If
            Else
                If Trim(oRs.Fields("lmeIndirectExpenseID").Value) <> "" Then
                    Fields("lmlExpenseID").Value = oRs.Fields("lmeIndirectExpenseID").Value
                End If
            End If
            If CInt(Fields("lmlTimecardType").Value) = 2 Then
                If Trim(oRs.FIelds("lmeDefaultWorkCenterID").Value) <> "" Then
                    Fields("lmlWorkCenterID").Value = oRs.FIelds("lmeDefaultWorkCenterID").Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

Capture1:

Fields("lmlExpenseID").Value = oRs.Fields("**lmeDirectExpenseID**").Value

Capture2:

Fields("lmlExpenseID").Value = oRs.Fields("**lmeIndirectExpenseID**").Value

*Capture3 (failed):*

Fields("lmlWorkCenterID").Value = oRs.FIelds("**lmeDefaultWorkCenterID**").Value

Comment: `Fields\("(\w+)"\)\.Value(?!\)?\s*[=<])` will probably also work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `(?:Fields\("(\w+)"\)\.Value)(?!\)?\s{0,2}[=|<])` *does* work in my Excel sheet, just not in the regex101 test. Probably a slightly different standard used there.

https://regex101.com/r/p6zFqy/1/

[image: passing pattern test]